# asp.net webforms type name conflict , currently page goes into error

Tags: asp.net

> CS0433: The type 'asp_XXX_ascx' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aa8e7042\2ecf8c99\xxxx.ascx.60cce07f.1fiwcbvl.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aa8e7042\2ecf8c99\App_Web_uynms6lu.dll'

Comment: Try delete  `Temporary ASP.NET Files` and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Open the folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files` and delete everything you see in it. It may show warnings like admin permissions required etc. Just choose to continue deleting.

If you are not able to delete something, stop IIS, delete it and then start it again.